# How to get all Tweets for a specified user OR a given hashtag?

Tags: php, xml, json, twitter

I'm trying to get a json/xml callback of all tweets for user 'zapallpeople' or containing hashtag '#zapallpeople'.
I've tried the search api but it will only return tweets from the last 6 days.
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:zapallpeople%20OR%20%23zapallpeople

Then I've tried doing this with the Streaming API's tracking method using the Phirehose PHP library but this doesn't work on our webserver for some reason. (I get a PHP timeout error)

```
<?php
require_once('../lib/Phirehose.php');
/**
 * Example of using Phirehose to display a live filtered stream using track words 
 */
class FilterTrackConsumer extends Phirehose
{
  /**
   * Enqueue each status
   *
   * @param string $status
   */
  public function enqueueStatus($status)
  {
    /*
     * In this simple example, we will just display to STDOUT rather than enqueue.
     * NOTE: You should NOT be processing tweets at this point in a real application, instead they should be being
     *       enqueued and processed asyncronously from the collection process. 
     */
    $data = json_decode($status, true);
    if (is_array($data) && isset($data['user']['screen_name'])) {
      print $data['user']['screen_name'] . ': ' . urldecode($data['text']) . "\n";
    }
  }
}

// Start streaming
$sc = new FilterTrackConsumer('username', 'password', Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
$sc->setTrack(array('zapallpeople'));
$sc->consume();
```

Are there any other methods to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no longer history available. See amongst other google hits [this link](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/08/12/twitter-search-history-dwindling-now-at-four-days/). It might be an oldy, but the concept stands: there is no longer search history then a couple of days, not exactly specified by twitter as far as I know.